# encoded json array getting corrupted in cookie when trying to decode json

Tags: php, json, cookies

I will explain below exactly what is happening. Any thoughts on a fix would be great thanks.

See below my PHP array..

```
$myArray = array( 145 => true, 134 => true, 152 => true);
```

My array then var dumped..

`array(3) { [145]=> bool(true), [134]=> bool(true), [152]=> bool(true) }`

I then json encode my array..

```
$myJson = json_encode($myArray);
```

My encoded json var dumped result is..

```
string(34) "{"145":true,"134":true,"152":true}"
```

I then set my cookie using the json string like this..

```
setcookie('mycookie', $myJson);
```

Then this is the cookie contents after it has been set..

```
%7B%22145%22%3Atrue%2C%22134%22%3Atrue%2C%22152%22%3Atrue%7D
```

**OK this where the trouble begins**

I then get the cookie contents using this..

```
$myCookie = $_COOKIE['mycookie'];
```

This a var dump of `$myCookie`..

```
string(40) "{\"131\":true,\"134\":true,\"152\":true}"
```

As you can see this not the same string that I set in the cookie. There are now backslashes like its being escaped or something. Why is this happing?

If I try and decode the json now it returns `NULL`.

Can anyone understand why this is happening? Surely I shouldn't have to string replace these back slashes? All I want to do decode the json. My original encoded string decodes fine, its just when it's added to the cookie, it corrupts my json.

Comment: What version of PHP is this running on? By any chance is it running on 5.3 or less and has [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) enabled?

Comment: PHP7, but i think i might have found a solution for now unless you got any other ideas. `$myArray = json_decode(stripslashes($_COOKIE['mycookie']), true)`

Comment: Unfortunately not. Frankly I'm surprised that it would be doing such a thing...

Comment: Its bizarre isn't it. When I read the cookie client slide using jQuery the json does not have any backslashes. So I can only assume that it is `$_COOKIE['mycookie']` which is adding the backslashes when retrieving the cookie.

Comment: Indeed, but that kind of functionality afaik was removed in 5.4...